# Puzzles for a small "magazine"

Tags: discussion

My parents and I have been solving puzzles together for many, many years. This upcoming Monday is my father's birthday, and I plan on compiling some of the puzzles that I've contributed here into a small "magazine" for my parents to solve in their free time.

I would love to use some puzzles from other members of the site, but I feel crummy using them without permission, so I'm asking here -- **If you have any puzzles you particularly like and would not mind being used in this gift,** please post links to them in an answer below! Hopefully I can load up a bunch of awesome puzzles and make a really cool little gift.

My parents (and I, not shockingly) prefer word puzzles and riddles over other puzzles, but things that are solvable without a computer, such as math puzzles, are okay as well. I'd like to avoid any sort of [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) puzzles because I want a list of puzzles that are solvable from any location. Technically, a lot of the ciphers *can* be solved from other locations, but I'm not going to ask my parents to figure out a Vigenere on the fly.

There are a few specific puzzles/users that I'm going to target as things I'd like to include, but for now I'm opening up the floor to see who wants to volunteer their best work.

Thanks ahead of time!

---

<sup>P.S. I have no idea if this is the right place for this, or how to tag it. If this can't/shouldn't be here, let me know.</sup>

Comment: You're welcome to anything of mine. Also, feeling crummy aside, note that technically you're allowed to take anything as long as you give attribution, since everything posted on any SE site is automatically "licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with attribution required".

Comment: @Alconja Although that wouldn't apply to puzzles [like this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/doctors-dilemma), which are being reproduced and discussed under Fair Use. (I'm sure it works for 99% of puzzles on the site, though.)

Comment: @Alconja my goal is to get recommendations from people who are excited about their own puzzles, as I'd like to include the things that people are really proud of. :) I'll snag a few of yours for sure though, and I'll make sure you know which ones I do!

Comment: Feel free to add any of mine to the mix - up to and including the unsolved epic of the Donut Phrases, they'll probably love that.

Comment: @BaileyM - just wondering if you ever ended up making your magazine, and if so what you included?

Answer (score 1):

Two of mine that I'm fond of (and the community too, according to their votes):

[Hearken, now, and listen close!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18509/hearken-now-and-listen-close)
[A Massive and Torrid Affair](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/a-massive-and-torrid-affair)

If you're looking for word puzzles and riddles, I think they fit the bill well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of mine that you want. Here are the best word puzzles that can definitely be solved without any additional resources:

[Letter to the Editor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/letter-to-the-editor)

[Strange Short Stories](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/strange-short-stories)

[Beneath the Waves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11349/beneath-the-waves)